# is there a better way to exclude navigationBarTitle for tvOS?

Tags: ios, swiftui, tvos

... to reuse a view with a navigationBarTitle? Or do I really have to repeat everything...just without navigationBarTitle for tvos ?

```
 #if os(iOS)

    NavigationLink(destination: CountryDetails(countryInfo: self.$userData.countryInfos[countryInfosIndex(of: country.name)])
                                .environmentObject(self.userData)
                                .navigationBarTitle(Text(country.name), displayMode: .inline) // <<<<<<<< the only difference
                        ) {
                            EmptyView() 
                        }.frame(width: 1, height: 1) 
 #else
    NavigationLink(destination: CountryDetails(countryInfo: self.$userData.countryInfos[countryInfosIndex(of: country.name)])
                                .environmentObject(self.userData)
                        ) {
                            // CountryRow(country: country)
                            EmptyView() 
                        }.frame(width: 1, height: 1) 
 #endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach

```
extension View {
    public func iosnavigationBarTitle(_ title: Text, 
             displayMode: NavigationBarItem.TitleDisplayMode = .inline) -> some View {
#if os(iOS)
        return self.navigationBarTitle(title, displayMode: displayMode)
#else
        return self
#endif
    }
}
```